# Ignore (or return) if there is error in node-fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

```
try {

     fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
             console.log(data);
          });
 } 
  catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
  }
```

So sometimes I'm getting `ECONNRESET` Error from it, and I wish to just ignore it somehow.

Comment: Fetch is asynchronous, and returns a promise. The error you're getting doesn't get thrown until the promise completes whatever its asynchronous code does (in this case, gets the URL's response or the connection fails). Meanwhile, your `try...catch...` statement continues right on before the async code is done, before the error is thrown. So instead, with promises, you catch errors by appending `.catch(callback)` to them, similarly to `.then()`. The callback is a function that receives the error as its only argument.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk but where should I put it? before getting json or at the end?

Comment: You can attach a `.catch` anywhere in the promise chain, just like you could attach a `.then` anywhere in the chain. It will catch errors that are thrown in any function called before it in the chain. So if you only want to catch errors in the request, like connection errors, put it between the fetch and the JSON parsing. If you want it to catch *all* errors, put it at the end of the promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

check for `ECONNRESET` in the same place as checking status if that does not suffice